# Displaying a button inside a bootstrap carousel item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some data i am displaying using a bootstrap 5 carousel. However, the button i want to display isn't showing at all. There are other places i could place the button and have it display but i wont get the id value i am trying to bind.

How can i display the button so that the id is bound to the current image being displayed

This is the code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aab147a.jpg" class="d-block w-100 cs" alt="...">
    </div>
    
    <div class="carousel-item" v-for="(value,index) in image_viewer_data">
      <img class="d-block w-100"  :src="value" :id="index" >
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block float-right" @click="handleClick" :id="index">Delete Photo</button>   
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped my button around the caption div

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aab147a.jpg" class="d-block w-100 cs" alt="...">
    </div>
    
    <div class="carousel-item" v-for="(value,index) in image_viewer_data">
      <img class="d-block w-100"  :src="value" :id="index" >
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block float-right" @click="handleClick" :id="index">Delete Photo</button>  
       </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

and to access the id

```
handleClick (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert(event.target.id)
},
```